# Finding the manufacturer/model number of this PoE Switch

Tags: networking, switch, power-over-ethernet

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask this. If not, please direct me to a place for these types of questions.

I'm having difficulties finding the model number of a PoE switch. I've attached an image of it. Specifically, it's the one above the Dlink switch.

[image]

Does anybody know the model/manufacturer of that PoE switch? Usually switches/routers have the model number up front but this does not. It is just simply labeled "POE Switch." I've also checked the rear but nothing's on there as well.

I've checked Netgear, Dlink, TPLink PoE switches and it's nothing like their designs.

Anyone know?

Comment: if there is no make & model on it, it is probably a chinese knockoff

Comment: We are unable to identify the product based on the information you provided

Comment: It appears to be [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/high-power-POE-switch-48v-9-rj45-10-100mbps-ports-8-poe-for-dahua-hik-poe/32623397271.html?spm=2114.01020208.3.121.0cRMHj&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4,searchweb201603_8&btsid=fe8c476c-9610-4037-8566-31c5605d3a20) one. It is kind of just a generic Chinese model.

Comment: Appreciate the comments. @Ramhound Sorry but that's pretty much the information I can provide as it doesn't have any other else distinct properties other than it's an 8port POE switch without a brand name.

Comment: @n8te I just checked the link you provided and it seems that's the one. It looks pretty much the same. If you can post it as an answer. I'll gladly accept it as the answer for this question. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a somewhat generic Chinese model that can be found [here.](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/high-power-POE-switch-48v-9-rj45-10-100mbps-ports-8-poe-for-dahua-hik-poe/32623397271.html?spm=2114.01020208.3.121.0cRMHj&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_4,searchweb201603_8&btsid=fe8c476c-9610-4037-8566-31c5605d3a20)